gzipping files that look like gzip but are not - in bash
I need my file to be in proper .txt.gz format. That is the extension, but I can tell from the size they are not gzipped correctly.
I can't zip my file, [because it is already .txt.gz], but I also can't unzip it to re-zip it again properly? See errors below [in bash]
gunzip file.txt.gz
gzip: file.txt.gz: not in gzip format
gzip file.txt.gz
gzip: file.txt.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged


This is the same if I use gzip -d
Any help is appreciated!

Rename the file to file.txt and gzip it?

Didn;t realise was that simple - thanks!

Read The Fine Manual  man gzip ... gzip -f file.gz : -f --force : Force compression or decompression even if the file has multiple links or the corresponding file already exists, or if the compressed data is read from or written to a terminal. If the input data is not  in  a format  recognized by gzip, and if the option --stdout is also given, copy the input data without change to the standard output: let zcat behave as cat.  If -f is not given, and when not running in  the  background, gzip prompts to verify whether an existing file should be overwritten.

What format is the file actually in? You can use file file.txt.gz to try to recognize the contents' format.

Rename the file to file.txt to make it gzippable.
mv file.txt.gz file.txt
gzip file.txt

Just make sure you don't overwrite an already existing file.
